# How can i adjust width and height of google map

Tags: javascript, regex, google-maps, size, window-resize

The width and and height of my google map is very small. I need 400px width and height. But I am getting 256px. The map_canvas div have 400px width and height.How can I change the width and height of Google map. Please help me.

```
<form id="overlay_form" style="display:none" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/x.png" id="close"/> 
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".popup").click(function(){
        $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
        positionPopup();
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});

    function positionPopup(){
    if(!$("#overlay_form").is(':visible')){
        return;
        }
        $("#overlay_form").css({
            left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
            top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
            position:'absolute'
        });
    }

   $(window).bind('resize',positionPopup);

</script>
```

Comment: Can't you change `map_canvas` css? AFAIK you could set height and width in css for the map_canvas.

Comment: Google map is displaying in a popup, and its width and height is 500px;

Comment: Please post code for that popup and how you are displaying along with css.

Comment: <form id="overlay_form" style="display:none" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/x.png"  id="close"/>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>

</form>

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK google's `map_canvas` div doesn't supports `height` and `width` in `%`, you'l need to explicitely specify in `pixels` only. So change your code as follows:

```
<form id="overlay_form" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/x.png" id="close"/> 
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
</form>
```

I've also removed `style="display:none"` from `<form ..>`. So that it will show map on screen.

See this, to understand [issue of height/width in % for google map.](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

Here is [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async)

Comment: instead pasting code in comments. please edit your question and add to that. Here in comments its very difficult to read code.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async . Solved the issue.Thankyou.